# Script tags are removed by jquery

Tags: jquery, tags

How can I load an external file into a div when the external file contains script tags.  There seems to be two issues; from what I have read jquery strips the script tags and second can't load to innerhtml.  I have switch to jquery .load but the stripping of the script tags is still an issue.  How do I solve this?  Thanks

```
<form id = "login_user" action="login/login_process.php" method="post">

    <label for="login_username">Username:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="login_username" name="login_username" value="" placeholder="Required" maxlength="20" minlength="2" size="20" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_]{2,20}$" onkeyup="validate_field('Username', 'login_username_pattern_message', document.getElementById('login_username'))" autofocus required>
    <div class="tooltip">?
      <span class="tooltiptext"><script>document.write(username_requirement)</script></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p id="login_username_pattern_message" ></p>

    <label for="login_password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="login_password" name="login_password" value="" placeholder="Required" maxlength="40" minlength="8" size="40" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" onkeyup="validate_field('Password', 'login_password_pattern_message', document.getElementById('login_password'))" required> 
    <div class="tooltip">?
      <span class="tooltiptext"><script>document.write(password_requirement)</script></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p id="login_password_pattern_message" ></p>
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" id="login_submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#login_user").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        
        $.ajax({
          url: url;
          type: request_method,
          data: form_data
        }).done(function(response){
          /*$("#login_combination_message").html(response);*/
          var msg = "";
          if(response==1)
          {
            msg = "Please Enter A Valid Username/Password Combination";
          }
          else
          {
            msg = "Username Or Password Character Requirement Error";
          }
          $("#login_combination_message").html(msg);
        });
      });
   });
</script>
```

```
<?php
include_once '../../login_helper/config.php';
include_once 'regexp.php';
include_once 'login_create_functions.php';
// DEBUG *********************************************************************
include 'login_create_user_debug.php';
// DEBUG ********************************************************************* 

$validate_username = $_POST['login_username'];
$validate_password = $_POST['login_password'];
$num_of_rows = 0;
$error_message = 0;

// validate uername and password patterns
validate_patterns(); // PHP Validation

// Is the username & password combination correct
if ($valid_username_pattern && $valid_password_pattern)
{
    // Prepare stmt to prevent SQL Injection
    $sql =  "SELECT user_id, user_password
             FROM User_Login
             WHERE user_username = ?
             ";

    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $validate_username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $user_password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if ($num_of_rows == 1 && password_verify($validate_password, $user_password))
    {
        //echo 'Username/Password Verified!';

        // DEBUG *********************************************************************
          helper_path();
        // DEBUG *********************************************************************

        // NOTE

?>

        <script>
            var url = "product_splash.html?message=0";
            window.location.replace(url);
        </script>

<?php

    }

    $error_message = 1;
    

}
else
{
    $error_message = 2;

}

// DEBUG *********************************************************************
//login_process_debug();
// DEBUG *********************************************************************


// RESPONSE TO AJAX

/*$return_value = username_password_error_ajax($error_message);*/

//echo $return_value;

echo json_encode($error_message);
    
exit();
?>
```

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&family=Noto+Sans&family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ohs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page_container">

        <div id="nav_bar">
        </div>

        <div id="header">
        </div>

        <div id="main">
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
<script>loadLink('splash/home_nav_bar.html', 'nav_bar')</script>
<!--<script>loadLink('splash/home_header.html', 'header')</script>-->
<script>loadLink('splash/home_main.html', 'main')</script>
<script>loadLink('splash/home_footer.html', 'footer')</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the issues is: the form and <jquery script> is inside a <div> that was loaded into the main page.  So when the form is submitted the <script> is not being recognized?  None of the <script>s are working after that segment is loaded into what I call <div id="main> of the page. So, the query $.post is loaded into the "main".   What is the correct method to handle such a case?

Comment: With more testing: the scripts tags are the issue.  How do you load an element to a page from an external file that contains script tags using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try return false after $.ajax({})

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#login_user").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        
        $.ajax({
          url: url;
          type: request_method,
          data: form_data
        }).done(function(response){
          /*$("#login_combination_message").html(response);*/
          var msg = "";
          if(response==1)
          {
            msg = "Please Enter A Valid Username/Password Combination";
          }
          else
          {
            msg = "Username Or Password Character Requirement Error";
          }
          $("#login_combination_message").html(msg);
        });
        return false;
      });
   });
```

Comment: Just tried adding return false;  Same result. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You've placed a semicolon after the url parameter inside ajax, you should use a comma instead:

from:
`url : url;`

to:
`url : url,`

Comment: Thanks for that catch.  I changed it and still the same response.  The url loads instead of the response being returned.  I've deleted everything and rewritten this many times.  Hoping it is something simple but since I'm new to Ajax Jquery I may simply be missing something fundamental.